# OIDC generalized scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, authorization, openid-connect

Currently building up a microservice for handling auth-related stuff using OIDC.
Now, we think about access control and how to be as future-proof as possible. This auth server is only used for first-party applications (3x SPA, 2x native mobile App). On mobile, we use the `authorization_code` grant. Each resource server validates the supplied token (access token as JWT) itself. But what happens when (in future), we add a service which needs its own scope to check (e.g. notifications:read)? As mobile app users are not used to logging in and out everytime (when we would update the requested scopes via an app update -> bad solution) is there any sweet solution to manage this scenario?

Per specification, it's possible to change the required scopes when refreshing a token but this is limited to require less scopes than originally requested and not more so that's not an option.

For example, Facebook is providing only four scopes for Instagram e.g. `instagram_basic` or `instagram_content_publish`. Zalando for example includes only a scope `NORMAL_USER` in their tokens whereas Wolt includes the users `roles` as a claim.

I think there is some confusion as this scenario is not covered directly by OAuth2 or OIDC. What are your thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1):

There is one standard for doing [OAuth 2.0 Incremental Authorization](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-incremental-authz-04), but your challenge is to find a token provider that supports it or similar standards.

In a micro service architecture, the question is if you should use the access token from the authorization code flow everywhere, or if for service-to-service communication, you should use client credentials flow instead.

See also https://www.gmass.co/blog/oauth-incremental-authorization-is-useless/

Comment: Thanks mate! For inter-service communication, the client credentials flow is used indeed so thats quite easy. The current painpoint applies only for communication from the public web/native apps with the API. We're using node-oidc-provider so that's quite easy to customize.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use [Token Exchange](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/#exchanging-a-token) for that.

For example it could work like that - whenever your resource server gets a token without the `notifications:read` scope, issued before date x (so before you were issuing that scope) it performs an exchange with the authorization server and (if the server decides that it can perform the exchange) it gets a new access token that contains that scope. If the token was issued after date x you can safely assume that the token was not granted this scope.

Another solution would be to use claims for authorization decisions instead of scopes. The authorization server can issue e.g. a claim `notifications_read: true`, or something like that. Whenever you refresh tokens you can issue more claims in the new access token, the spec does not prevent that. Then your resource servers should check claims in the access token, they can ignore scopes. The resource server would just check whether the token contains the `notifications_read` claim with value `true`, or not. This solution gets a bit more complicated if you require your users to give consent to scopes, but as you said you're using this only for 1st-party, so I assume you're not using consent screens.

You can have a look at [this free course](https://curity.io/resources/webinars/course-building-identity-architecture) - this topic of using claims in authorization is covered in part 4.